# Slack app interactive message callback, username from payload not display name

Tags: node.js, webhooks, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

We have created a Slack app that can respond to interactive messages (with blocks), i.e. a message with a clickable button. The app is configured correctly so when a user clicks the button a payload is sent to the request callback URL defined for our app.

The Slack JSON payload we receive contains a `user` object of the interacting user. However, the `username` field looks like an ID and is not the human readable display name.

Here is a redacted example of the payload sent by Slack to our request URL.

```
{
    "type": "block_actions",
    "user": {
        "id": "U04xxxxxx",
        "username": "00u6xxxxxxxx",
        "name": "00u6xxxxxxxx",
        "team_id": "T3xxxxx"
    },
    "api_app_id": "A021XXXXXX",
    "token": "xxx",
    "channel": {...},
    "message": {...}
}
```

Both, the `username` and `name` fields are set to the same coded value and not the display name. Is there a setting in the Slack app for this? I don't have access to administer the Slack app settings.

Comment: If you run `users.info` on that `U` user id do you get the same values for the name and username? Are you getting similar results for other users or is it just for that one specific user? It could just be that that user was recently provisioned into the workspace and hasn't changed their profile info yet?

Comment: I will try calling the user info API. However, one of the accounts is my own profile and I do have a display name set and it is still not showing the display name.

Comment: Are you able to replicate the behaviour from a different workspace?

Comment: I am only a developer on a particular workspace and do not have access to any others. We did notice that our slack app did not have the "users:read" permission. After adding this, it still did not fix the app issue. However, when calling the "user.info" endpoint we can see that the user has the "real_name" correctly defined. So there must be an issue with the interactive message api.

Comment: Strange, you may want to bring this to feedback@slack.com they should be able to tell you whether you're dealing with a bug.